# Dragged items and jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to move the item while scrolling the page

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    $("#profile").offset({top:scrollTop+34});
});
```

And this code to show and hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various[type=profile]").click(function() {
        if($("#profile").attr("clicked") == "yes") {
            $("#profile").stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){$("#profile").css("visibility", "hidden")}, 1000);
            $("#profile").attr("clicked", "");
        }
        else {          
            $("#profile").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#profile").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
            $("#profile").attr("clicked", "yes");
        }
    });
});
```

This is css

```
#profile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The problem is that the item returns to it's initial position (top: 34px, right: 0px) with every click. With using fadeIn/fadeOut I have the same problem.

Comment: I would say try to switch using `$('elem').css()` to `$('elem').addClass('class')`. Adding a css class for the visibility of course. I am not sure but that css function "could" be overwriting the style created for the drag and drop.

Comment: can you make a fiddle for us to test?

Comment: No, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just look into jQuery UI.  They have code that can already make tags draggable and droppable.  They are easy to define too.

```
$("#profile").draggable();
```

http://jqueryui.com

Comment: As I know draggable is used for drag item with mouse.

Comment: You want to then do what drag an item with a scroll?

Comment: Page is scrolling and item is scrolling with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to do here.

**1:** Rather than positioning the element with jQuery, you can just use the CSS property `position:fixed` to stick it in the upright corner.

```
#profile {
    position: fixed;
    top: 34px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**2:** There are a some issues with your jQuery code for showing and hiding. First, `clicked` is not a valid HTML attribute. You should consider using `$(element).data('clicked')` instead of `$(element).attr('clicked')` to store its visibility. Next, when you set `visibility:hidden`, the `click` event no longer registers on it, so clicking on it won't show it again.

Maybe [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LCs4/) is the effect you're looking for?

Comment: Not 'checked', but 'clicked'. Maybe it's right to use $(elem).data() on the part of good writing code, but '$(elem).attr('clicked') also works fine. And about visibility... It shows it again, but I should use animate callback function to set visibility:hidden.

Comment: 'Position:fixed ' didn't help.

Comment: I don't know why I started saying "checked," hahah. A little too used to answering questions about radio buttons. As for the visibility, when it's set to `hidden`, the element won't show up again when I click the space it used to occupy. I've only tested this in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Maybe there was this bug. Now I have this  if($("#profile").attr("clicked") == "yes") {
   $("#profile").stop().animate({
    opacity: 0
   }, 
   1000,
   function() {
    $("#profile").css("visibility", "hidden");  
   });  
   $("#profile").attr("clicked", ""); 
  }  And it works well :)

Comment: 'Well' it's not about general problem.

Comment: Completely forgot, [this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/3LCs4/)  has the same problem: the element after scrolling the page when you click back to the starting position and then disappears or appears

Comment: Is the `#profile` supposed to reappear at the top of the scrollable content -- and not the fixed position -- when you click on it again? I'm afraid I don't quite understand what it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: Yes `#profile` should reappear at the top of the content. For example I scrolled page for 20px so `#profile` must be shown by click at `top:54` and `right:0`. But it is shown at it's first coordinates which are `top:34` and `right:0`. Now I use `position:fixed`, but there is no any different with `position:absolute`.

Comment: And if `#profile` was already shown and page was scrolled after that, then by click page scrolls to top and only then `#profile` dissapears.